# Sharing a class between multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I need help figuring this question out. I've tried searching and I think I might have found a solution using a Singleton Design pattern, but want to make sure.

I have a Windows forms app I am writing in Visual C#. I am writing a SerialPort class so it can be shared via all the forms (I don't need multiple serial port instances). This is to separate the logic from the GUI. All forms can make various changes to SerialPort class such as baud rate, write, read, etc.

What is the best way to implement this solution? I'm new to OOP so any recommendations on readings would be great.

Comment: Can your serial class be entirely static? Or does there need to be _an_ instance of it somewhere?

Comment: The only time there wouldn't be an instance would be if the user doesn't want to update a particular unit, thus no need for serial. I am not sure if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to @Luiggi's solution, here's one a bit more thread conscience:

```
public sealed class SerialPort
{
  private static volatile SerialPort instance;
  private static object threadLock = new Object();

  /// <summary>Retrieve an instance of SerialPort</summary>
  public static SerialPort Instance
  {
    get
    {
      if (SerialPort.instance == null)
      {
        lock (SerialPort.threadLock)
        {
          if (SerialPort.instance == null)
          {
            SerialPort.instance == new Serialport();
          }
        }
      }
      return SerialPort.instance;
    }
  }

  private SerialPort(){}
}
```

Then, in practice:

```
SerialPort sp = SerialPort.Instance;
sp.MyMethod(...);
```

More information on [this Singleton pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Comment: Would initializaiton of the SerialPort classs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) be done under: 
private SerialPort(){}?

For example: SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();

Comment: I named it `SerialPort` just going by what you mentioned for a name and that you said a class you were writing. With that being said, the private construct is what is called, yes. But you can't ever do `SerialPort sp = new Serialport()`. The constructor is privatized so nothing can instantiate it other than calling the `Instance` property

Comment: Yea sorry I should have re-phrased. I am taking the SerialPort class from the .NET library and making a class based on that so it can be shared amongst forms.

Comment: @brazc0re: Then rename the class to somethign else and then use the `SerialPort` class within.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Brad Christie. I should be on my way using Singletons. I'll be reading more about the design pattern as I use it.

Answer (score 3):

As you already said, this problem can be solved using the Singleton Design Pattern. Here is a small sample:

```
public class MySingleton() {
    private static MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();

    //your attributes go here...
    private MySingleton() {
    //your logic goes here...
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Note that if your static instance will be used for multiple threads, your class should lock the shared resources. I'll let you a reference to [Thread Safe Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37976/Writing-Thread-Safe-Code-in-C)

Comment: Thanks. Yes there will be multiple threads in the program. The serial communication will most likely be implemented in a BackgroundWorker thread. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I've just ran into the same problem yesterday, and I think I might have found a much easier way of approaching this matter instead of using the singleton method. I made a class file and created a class called `public class Serial`. Inside I declared my serial variable as `static SerialPort` (i.e. `static SerialPort serial`); same with a timer if you need to use one. Create a function for set and get called `serialStatus`, where it sets a `public static bool`. I really would like to post my code here, but I really don't understand how to properly do it. In your form, you would have the first form start the serial port. For the other form, all you  have to do is declare `Serial serial = new Serial();` pull out the methods, and you're good to go. If you need to make changes to the serial settings, you can create a method with a bool input (i.e. if `true`, `serial.Close();` then restart serial with new settings.