# Share class between forms

Tags: c#, .net

Say I want to use a custom class to store user settings, and save it using XML Serialize. 
When the program is started, it deserializes the XML file.
I now have a class containing all the user settings.

How can I now share this class with all the other forms in my application?
Is there a better way than passing it along as a parameter to the constructors?

Ideally I'd use a static class, but this has no instance, and so it's not serializable.
I'd like something like the .NET properties file, which is accessible everywhere. 
(Unfortunately this only allows pairs, which isn't good enough - hence my own XML file)

Edit:

Based on the answers I now have this:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class UserSettings
{
    private static readonly UserSettings _instance = new UserSettings();
    private string _FirstName;
    private string _LastName;       

    public static UserSettings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    static UserSettings()
    {            
    }

    private UserSettings()
    {
        //Constructor
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _FirstName; }
        set { _FirstName = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _LastName; }
        set { _LastName = value; }
    }       
}
```

I have serialized and saved an instance of this class, containing values, to a file. 
I use this code to load it:

```
    private static void LoadUserSettings()
    {
        UserSettings us = UserSettings.Instance;

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream(_AppSettingsFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        us = (UserSettings)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(us.FirstName + " " + us.LastName);
    }
```

When I read the properties in the LoadUserSettings function (the commented last line) it shows the values that were saved. 

However, when I run this code in my Form_load, the values are empty. (In fact, everything is NULL):

```
       LoadUserSettings();
       UserSettings us = UserSettings.Instance;                    
       MessageBox.Show(us.FirstName + " " + us.LastName);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I like passing it into the constructor. To make that easier, use an IOC container (e.g. Unity, StructureMap, etc.). That will allow you to keep your code structured as is but to automatically inject the values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing a class between multiple forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325040/sharing-a-class-between-multiple-forms)

Answer (score 2):

Since it represents state that is logically "global" and not something that should be allowed to exist as multiple instances you were right to think it should be static.  Since you need to have an actual instance of the object it means that the appropriate solution is to use a Singleton.  This will give you an instance that you can serialize, but that instance can be exposed throughout the application, and you can be sure there will only ever be exactly one of it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, make it a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

```
public sealed class UserSettings
{
    private static readonly UserSettings _instance = new UserSettings();
    public static UserSettings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    static UserSettings()
    {
    }

    private UserSettings()
    {
        // do constructor logic here
    }
}
```

and now you can access it like this:

```
UserSettings.Instance.SomeProperty
```

Comment: @Servy, please edit if you don't mind showing us all your understanding of it.

Comment: And how would I initialise this? And add functions and properties to it?

Comment: @user1970043, you want to create properties for all the settings and then set those properties in the constructor.