# c# sharing a class between multiple forms

Tags: c#

I have been looking around and found some answers with the same question as me, however i did try the code and it didn't work in my case.
I tried to do the same thing as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325040/sharing-a-class-between-multiple-forms). My aim is to enable many different forms to use a class to do something.

Here are the part of simplified version of my class:

```
public class test
{
somedll g = new somedll();
somedll h = new somedll();

public void Stop(int module)
    {
        string command = "STOP";
        if (module == 1)
        {
            this.WriteCommand(1, command);
        }
        else if (module == 2)
        {
            this.WriteCommand(2, command);
        }
    }

private void WriteCommand(int module, string command)
    {
        try
        {
            if (module == 1)
            {
                g.write(command + '\r');
            }
            else if (module == 2)
            {
                h.write(command + '\r');
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (module == 1)
            {
                gconnected = false;
            }
            else if (module == 2)
            {
                hconnected = false;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("<Write failed> Please connect.");
        }
    }
```

As my problems is i am unable to use static to make my class to be able to shared by all forms, as static is more efficient in just sharing variable/data.

edit*: I dont actually need static, i just need to make this class accessible from all other forms, without declaring new instances, i mentioned static because i did tried to used it and it cant compile.

The problem with not creating multiple instances is due to i need the data to be centralized. As declaring multiple instances cause all forms to get independent data.

edit*: My aim is to use this class that i show above with other forms without creating new instances from each forms. For example, in each form1, form2, form3 and form4, i will need to access 'stop', and then stop will in turn call 'writecommand' to finally send out the command. So, due to there is some calling in the method, static is unable to use(in my field of knowledge in c# only

Is there anyway to solve this? thanks

Comment: Why do you need `static`? Where do you reference this and how? What are `g` and `h`?

Comment: It is not clear what your question is, please explain more.

Comment: @PatrickHofman g & h is just a instance declaration for another dll. it is shown on the beginning of the code. I dont actually need static, i just need to make this class accessible from all other forms, without declaring new instances.

Comment: @ShellShock my question is to use this class that i show above with other forms without creating new instances for each forms. It is unable to use static in this due to i need to use the dll to perform the task needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a single instance of your class to multiple forms (either through the constructor or via a property). However, you will probably need to make your class thread-safe by using locking.

A static instance of your non-static class would be another way for your forms to access a single instance, but this is not usually the best approach as it more tightly couples the class and the forms.

EDIT

To expand, a static instance of your non-static class Could look like this:

```
public class test
{
    private static test singleInstance = new test();
    public static test SingleInstance { get { return singleInstance; } }

    somedll g = new somedll();
    somedll h = new somedll();

    public void Stop(int module)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private void WriteCommand(int module, string command)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or it could be in another class altogether.

The other (possibly better) approach would be to create a new instance in the code that creates your forms, and to pass it to the forms' constructors, which could be edited to be something like this:

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    private readonly test testInstance;

    public MyForm(test testInstance)
    {
        this.testInstance = testInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I can actually try it out if there is no other solution.. But do you mind share me some example for transfer the instance?
like, after declare 'public static somedll g = new somedll' and then 'frm1 form1 = new frm1(g)' and den what changes should i put inside frm1? please do enlighten me! thanks

Comment: Yes! method2 works better for me. i just need to add some flags for prevention and it is working. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to create an instance of your class, change it's value from one form and want the changed value of this instance to be reachable from other forms. You said you cannot use static for that, but I think you can. Have you tried using a static class like:

```
static class YourClass
{
    private static string _yourVar= "";
    public static string YourVar
    {
        get { return _yourVar; }
        set { _yourVar = value; }
    }
}
```

and change it like:

```
YourClass.YourVar = "your value"
```

I highly recommend reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325040/sharing-a-class-between-multiple-forms).

Comment: yup.. i did read that thread before i posted. 
Also, for example, in each form1, form2, form3 and form4, i will need to access stop, and then stop will in turn call writecommand to finally send out the command. So, due to the fact that there is some calling in the method, static is unable to use(*in my field of knowledge in c# only*).

Comment: if you call a method from a static class, the method should be static. just add "static" to your function definition as I did in the answer.